# How To Order Labels from Several Layers in Mapserver?

Tags: labeling, mapserver

I have an Mapserver project with several layers. Some of the layers have labels.

My problem is that labels from one layer overlap the labels from another layer. I want the labels to change vertical order (Label 2 should be rendered over Label 1 instead of Label 1 over Label 2).

I've tried to play around with "Force True/False" and "Priority," but either the Label 1 is above Label 2 or Label 1 isn't displayed at all.

The issue is that Label 1 has to be displayed certainly on the given x/y-point while Label 2 has to be dynamically positioned, because it is labeling a polygon and should be displayed in every zoom resolution and every image section.

The polygon which is described by Label 1 is overlayed by the Polygon of Label 2 (but view-able due to Opacity Settings). Label 1 itself isn't overlayed or overlapped by anything.

I hope I've described my problem clearly - does somebody know how to do that?

Comment: One thing to consider is the drawing order of layers in MapServer; the layer that appears at the top of your map file will draw first, that is appear at the bottom of the map.  So the labels you want to be on top should be defined at the bottom of the map file